# Magento 2.1 :how to create export module in product attribute and attribute set

Tags: attributes, magento-2.1

How to export attributes in magento 2.1 backhand ,like when i want to export attributes  of particular attribute set

Answer (score 0):

Magento does not have **such type of functionality in default**.

For this case, you may be use some extension

https://marketplace.magento.com/emipro-importexportattributeoption.html

http://www.commerceextensions.com/magento-import-export-bulk-product-attributes-magento-2.html

Or need to do customization in your system

Comment: yes,default was not there thats why i want to add module for export.